# Hibernate exception: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've these (simplified) tables in my database

[image]

I've mapped the tables with these (simplified) two classes

**COMPANY**

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name="company_employee", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="company_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")})
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private SortedSet<Employee> employees = new TreeSet<Employee>();

    // contructors + getters + setters
 }
```

**EMPLOYEE**

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     private String name;

     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
     @JoinTable(name="company_employee", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="company_id")}
     )
     private Company company;

     @Override
     public int compareTo(Employee anotherEmployee) {
          return this.name.compareTo(anotherEmployee.name);
     }

     // contructors + getters + setters + equals + hashcode
 }
```

I'm using a `SortedSet/TreeSet` in employees defined in `Company` to obtain the employees sorted by name.

The problem arises when I persist the objects. I've read that you must establish the relation in both sides. I set the employee in company and the company in the employee before persisting the company. When I try to execute the persist, I'm obtaining the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:86)
    at es.rubioric.hibernate.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:43)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:67)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1314)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2890)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '32-80' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2643)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 18 more
```

This is a simplified code that generates that exception. [EDITED commit location after comment by @NicolasFilotto]

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

         EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDB");

         EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
         EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
         tx.begin();

        try {
             Company c = new Company("Nike");

             Employee e1 = new Employee("Anthony");
             e1.setCompany(c);  // line 26
             Employee e2 = new Employee("Zenobia");
             e2.setCompany(c);   // line 28
             Employee e3 = new Employee("Chuck");
             e3.setCompany(c);   // line 30
             Employee e4 = new Employee("Bernard");
             e4.setCompany(c);  // line 32

             c.getEmployees().add(e1);
             c.getEmployees().add(e2);
             c.getEmployees().add(e3);
             c.getEmployees().add(e4);

             em.persist(c);

             tx.commit();

        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

These are the SQL sentences internally executed by Hibernate.

```
Hibernate: insert into Company (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into company_employee (company_id, employee_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into company_employee (company_id, employee_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into company_employee (company_id, employee_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into company_employee (company_id, employee_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into company_employee (company_id, employee_id) values (?, ?)
```

The same code works perfectly if I comment lines 26, 28, 30 and 32 (marked above). But I want to know why is that exception being generated. Why the duplicated key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add persist(c); before Employee e1..

Comment: NB: I don't believe that it is a good idea to call tx.commit() in a finally block

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Got the same exception. Why is not a good idea to place the commit inside the finally block?

Comment: because if you have an exception in the try block, why calling commit? moreover with your code if commit fails close is never called

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Ah, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: Try to create and persist first your Employee instances then create your Company instance, call setCompany for each  Employee instance and add e1, e2, e3 and e4 to c.getEmployees()

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thanks but I can persist the entities correctly just commenting lines 26, 28 etc. but I don't know why that exception is being generated. I'm curious. Your method implies more code (more persist sentences) than I have already and that not answer my question.

Comment: I know but I suspect that the JPA implementation is not capable of creating the new entities and adding a join for each new entities. It seems to work for one but not for 4 try to comment lines 28, 30 and 32

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Got the same exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The duplicates are caused by your company-employee relationship being duplicated in both entities.  Each has been setup as a unidirectional 1:M (one side is using a 1:1 for some reason), and both are using the same join table, causing duplicates when JPA goes to insert entries for both sides.

The solution is to mark one side as 'mappedby' the other.

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy="company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@OrderBy("name ASC")
private SortedSet<Employee> employees = new TreeSet<Employee>();
```

Comment: I though that Hibernate can detect and avoid the duplication on inserting in the link table. I didn't know that I can not mark both unidirectional at the same time. Thanks for the answer.